# antd Table not showing the first row

Tags: antd, react-query

I am using react-query to fetch the users data to display via antd Table. The problem is that I am receiving 4 documents, while antd displays 3 in Table.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIKn4.png)
[image of a log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAn5l.png)

This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Table, notification, Popconfirm, Button, Spin, Input, Alert } from 'antd';
import { DeleteOutlined, EditOutlined, SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { SERVER_URL } from '../../config';
import { UserContext } from '../../App';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

let filterData = {
  firstName: undefined,
  lastName: undefined,
  email: undefined,
  page: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
};

const UsersList = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const currentuser = useContext(UserContext);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(filterData);
  const [working, setWorking] = useState(false);
  const [fetchTrigger, setFetchTrigger] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    filterData = { ...filterData, ..._.pickBy(_.get(history, 'location.state', null), _.identity) };
    setFilter(filterData);
  }, [history]);

  // react query
  async function fetchUsers(filter) {
    const params = _.pickBy(filter, _.identity);

    setWorking(true);

    const { data } = await Axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/users`, {
      withCredentials: false,
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentuser.data.token}` },
      params,
    });

    // setUsers(data);

    setWorking(false);

    console.log('DATA', data);

    return data;
  }

  const { data, isError, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['users-all', filter, fetchTrigger],
    queryFn: () => fetchUsers(filter),
    keepPreviousData: true,
  });

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    try {
      setWorking(true);

      await Axios.delete(`${SERVER_URL}/users/${id}`, {
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentuser.data.token}` },
      });

      setFetchTrigger(!fetchTrigger);

      setWorking(false);

      notification.success({
        message: 'Success',
        description: 'User deleted.',
        placement: 'bottomRight',
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setWorking(false);
      console.log(error);
      notification.error({
        message: 'Error',
        description: 'Problem with deleting user. Please try later.',
        placement: 'bottomRight',
      });
    }
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'FIRST NAME',
      dataIndex: ['firstName'],
      key: 'firstName',
      align: 'center',
      // ...getColumnSearchProps(['firstName']),
    },
    {
      title: 'LAST NAME',
      dataIndex: ['lastName'],
      key: 'lastName',
      align: 'center',
      // ...getColumnSearchProps(['lastName']),
    },
    {
      title: 'EMAIL',
      dataIndex: ['email'],
      key: 'email',
      align: 'center',
      // ...getColumnSearchProps(['email']),
    },
    {
      title: 'PREMIUM',
      dataIndex: 'premium',
      key: 'premium',
      align: 'center',
      render: (text, record) => (record.premium ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'),
      // ...getColumnSearchProps(['premium']),
    },
    {
      title: 'PHONE NUMBER',
      dataIndex: 'phoneNumber',
      key: 'phoneNumber',
      align: 'right',
      render: (text, record) => (record.phoneNumber ? record.phoneNumber : 'N/A'),
      // ...getColumnSearchProps('name'),
    },
    {
      title: 'CREATED AT',
      dataIndex: 'createdAt',
      key: 'createdAt',
      align: 'right',
      render: (text, record) => new Date(record.createdAt).toLocaleString('en-US'),
    },
  ];

  columns.push({
    title: 'ACTION',
    key: 'action',
    align: 'center',
    render: (text, record) => {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            fontSize: '15px',
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ margin: '2px', padding: '4px', cursor: 'pointer' }} className='table-actions'>
            <EditOutlined onClick={() => history.push(`/admin/view-user/${record._id}`)} />
          </div>

          <div style={{ margin: '2px', padding: '4px', cursor: 'pointer' }} className='table-actions'>
            <Popconfirm
              title='Are you sure you want to delete this user?'
              onConfirm={async () => handleDelete(record._id)}
              onCancel={() => console.log('Cancel')}
              okText='Yes'
              cancelText='No'
            >
              <DeleteOutlined />
            </Popconfirm>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    },
  });

  const onChangeTable = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
    Object.keys(filters).map((prop) => {
      filter[prop] = Array.isArray(filters[prop]) ? filters[prop][0] : filters[prop];
    });

    setFilter({ ...filter, ...{ page: pagination.current, pageSize: pagination.pageSize } });
  };

  //table usersWrapper
  return (
    <div className='content-wrapper'>
      {isError && <Alert message={'Loading data problem...'} type='error' showIcon closable />}
      <Spin spinning={working} tip='Loading...'>
        <div className='actions-block' style={{ marginBottom: '8px' }}>
          {/* <Input
          bordered={false}
          placeholder='Search'
          prefix={<SearchOutlined />}
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        /> */}
          <Button onClick={() => console.log(1)} type='primary'>
            Add user
          </Button>
        </div>

        {data && data.length > 0 && (
          <div className='table-user-okvir'>
            <Table
              size='middle'
              onChange={onChangeTable}
              bordered
              columns={columns}
              dataSource={[...data]}
              rowKey={(record) => record._id}
              // rowSelection={rowSelection}
              pagination={{
                pageSize: filter.pageSize || 10,
                total: !isLoading ? data.length : 0,
                current: filter.page || 1,
              }}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </Spin>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function () {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      <UsersList />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

// export default UsersList;
```

I tried to map and display the data via  tag and it shows all 4. It seems the problem is with the Table itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding `scroll={{ y: 240 }}` which didn't actually add a scroll to my table but just expanded it a little bit and displayed the first row. Still have no idea why though xD...